# In the MySQL client/server protocol, how are compressed packets split?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, network-protocols, database-connection

The MySQL [client/server protocol docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.12/page_protocol_basic_compression_packet.html) say:

> **Note**
>
> sending a MySQL Packet of the size 2<sup>24</sup>-5 to 2<sup>24</sup>-1 via compression leads to at least one extra compressed packet. If the uncompressed MySQL Packet is like
>
> `fe ff ff 03 ... -- length = 2^24-2, sequence id = 3`
>
> compressing it would result in the *length of payload before compression* in the Compressed Packet Header being:
>
> ```
> length of mysql packet payload:       2^24-2
> length of mysql packet header:        4
> length of payload before compression: 2^24+2
> ```
>
> which can not be represented in one compressed packet. Instead two or more packets have to be sent.

What I don't understand is how the packet is split.

Is the entire MySQL compressed, and then separated? If so, how is it split, and what should the *length of payload before compression* field be set to?

Or is the MySQL packet split into chunks of max size 2<sup>24</sup>-1, and then sent in individual compressed packets with *length of payload before compression* set to `ff ff ff` in all but the last? This seems to be the more likely of the two, but I can't find any documentation for this detail.

Finally, if it is the latter, should the max packet size pre-compression be set to 2<sup>24</sup>-5, to prevent a scenario like the following:

```
Payload size: 0x100fffe (0xffffff + 0xffff)

MySQL Packets:
#1: length of payload = ff ff ff (size = 0x1000003)
#2: length of payload = ff ff 00 (size = 0x10003)

Compressed packets:
  MySQL Packet #1:
    #1: length of payload before compression = ff ff ff
    #2: length of payload before compression = 04 00 00
  MySQL Packet #2:
    #1: length of payload before compression = ff ff 00
```

Here 3 packets are compressed and sent, instead of just 2 if packets were split with max size 2<sup>24</sup>-5 at the MySQL Packet layer.

Comment: Surely you mean 2^24 and so on?

Comment: Compression is independent of splitting the transmission into packets.

Comment: @Barmar So how are packets with a pre-compression size greater than 0xffffff handled?

Comment: As the above says, in that case they become two compression packets. But initially the message is broken into packets ignoring compression, then compression might need to split it up again.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean by “they become two compression packets”?

Comment: It's the last line of the section you quoted: "Instead, two or more packets have to be sent".

Comment: @Barmar What gets split though? If it’s the compressed payload, what does the Compressed Packet Header look like for each packet?

Comment: If I understand the quoted material, the original uncompressed packet has to be split up, and sent as multiple compressed packets. Because the original packet's header is included in the payload of the compressed packet, and that makes the length overflow 24 bits.

Comment: @Barmar So the second option I stated in my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196109/discussion-between-benjy-wiener-and-barmar).